# How to force a ViewPager to reload its children from a child Fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, illegalstateexception

I have a `ViewPager` inside a `FragmentActivity`. The `ViewPager` uses a `FragmentPagerAdapter` and has these notable methods:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return ChildFragment.newInstance(MyActivity.this);
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

Within one of the child Fragments I modify the ViewPager's Adapter so that the order of the children changes. To force the ViewPager to update to reflect this change I call:

```
mViewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

However I get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions
```

If I put the call to notifyDataSetChanged() with an ASyncTask the exception goes away but the ViewPager does not update it's views.

Does anyone know the correct way to force a ViewPager to reload it's child views when notifyDataSetChanged() is called?

Thanks

Comment: This is a bug and can be addressed by creating a DataSetObserver. I thought you were using some pager implementation like SimplePager. What you need can be done here http://kwazico.com/2011/10/fragmentpageradapter-doesnt-respond-to-notifydatasetchanged/

Comment: Okay thanks for the information. I'll try this later and report back.

Comment: I tested this and it does not work. My custom `DataSetObserver` gets called but attempting to call the method `destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)` on each page only removes the view - you are left with a blank page. Not helpful at all.

I want the whole `ViewPager` to refresh all child views.